# How can i run an R markdown script automatically at set intervals on the cloud?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have an R script, that calls and runs several R markdown scripts which need to be run every day, preferably every hour. The belonging data files are continuously retrieved by MS Power Automate. Everything left for it to be fully automated is if the script could run by itself every day, or better, every hour. Preferably this would not require a physical pc to be on either. The RMD- and belonging data files are currently in a Sharepoint folder. Preferably the solution is cheap or free as well. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Rmarkdown isn't the content, it doesn't control itself. R is just the language in the Rmd file, it doesn't control when it is run. If you are using Connect or shiny-server or shinyapps.io, then they have their own controlling mechanisms for periodicity, etc. If you're looking for options on how to host an Rmd file on a server, then ... that's my list for options, unless you want a home-grown docker-based, in which case it'll be home-grown, I know of know off-the-shelf plug-in working server for this, many many things to configure and control.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks. I tested Github Pages which seemed to work well for hosting the HTML outputs. I want to create an automated "git commit and push" to the repository for the GitHub pages from the SharePoint library where the finished produced HTML files are. If I can get this to work then the HTML files that are hosted on GitHub Pages should self-update with each commit of an updated HTML file. Since the data files for knitting the RMDs are all retrieved automatically - the missing piece is to run the R-script which renders the individual RMD files automatically. Advice on solving this? :)

Comment: I don't know, this sounds better suited for SuperUser.com and not StackOverflow (since it is barely about programming). Perhaps it can be addressed with GitHub Actions. I know nothing about "commit and push" from SharePoint, that's completely out of my wheelhouse.